# Spring Boot Thrift

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, thrift

I am following this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/building-microservices-spring to use thrift on Spring. When I run the tutorial it runs fine however when I am doing an example it doesn't do the correct mapping.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class CacheApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CacheApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public TProtocolFactory tProtocolFactory() {
    return new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
}

@Bean
public Servlet cache(TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, CacheServiceHandler handler) {
    return new TServlet(new TCacheService.Processor<>(handler), protocolFactory);
}


}
```

This is my main, and when I start the server it says "Servlet cache mapped to [/]" when it shoud be "Servlet cache mapped to [/cache/]"

the tutorial is on gradle but I am using maven

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo_thrift</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>



<name>Demo  Thrift</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running the server I get no error, however when I run the client with this code

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {CacheApplication.class})

public class ClientTest {
    protected int port;

    @Autowired
    protected TProtocolFactory protocolFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(ClientTest.class).profiles("client").web(false).run(args);

    }
    @Bean
    public String test() throws Exception{
        TTransport transport= new THttpClient("http://localhost:8080/cache/");
        TProtocol protocol = protocolFactory.getProtocol(transport);
        TCacheService.Client client;
        client = new TCacheService.Client(protocol);
        return client.query(10);
    }

}
```

And this is the error I got:

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: HTTP Response code: 406
at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flush(THttpClient.java:352) ~[libthrift-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73) ~[libthrift-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62) ~[libthrift-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at com.example.demo.Generated.TCacheService$Client.send_query(TCacheService.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.Generated.TCacheService$Client.query(TCacheService.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.Client.ClientTest.test(ClientTest.java:36) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: Please include your code and error as well.

Comment: @want2learn error added

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by modifying the servlet bean as follows:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cache(TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, CacheServiceHandler handler) {
    TServlet servlet = new TServlet(new TCacheService.Processor<SampleServiceControllerHandler>(handler), protocolFactory);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/cache");
}
```